# using linked lists to add integers and read them

Tags: biginteger, doubly-linked-list

Infinite Adder

Write a program that can add 2 integers of ANY LENGTH (limited only by computer memory). Store the 2 integers as a linked list of digits (each node is a single digit from 0 – 9). Read each number from a comma-delimited file of digits in reverse order (for example, a file with “2,3,7,0,1” represents the number 10732). One file should be called “num1.txt” and the other file should be called “num2.txt”. The Hard Part: When you print out the answer, it should be in “normal” order.

It may be wise to write a doubly-linked list in order to make things easier.

Help would be very much appreciated.

I can tell you what I need to do, but I don't know how to write it code-wise.

Comment: Sounds a bit too much like homework. This site isn't a codewriting service - please have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I know, it is homework. I'm not asking for a full program. Just some help. It says "Help would be very much appreciated". Just need some guidance.

Comment: why you don't give it a try and when you get suck ask here?

Comment: The thing is, I have, my code's not working, and I'm not sure where to start from and what to do.

Comment: You could start by adding a tag for the language you are using, and by showing your code, even if it does not produce the desired result. You could also debug your code to try to find out where it goes wrong.